# Problems with nonlinear least square fit nls non-numeric argument with binary operator

Tags: r, nls

I just started working with R and would like to get a Nonlinear least square fit nls(...) to the formula y=A(1-exp(-bL))+R.
I define my function g by

```
> g<-function(x,y,A,b,R) {
    y~A(1-exp(-bx))+R
    }
```

and want to perform nls by

```
>nls((y~g(x,y,A,b,R)),data=Data, start=list(A=-2,b=0,R=-5))
```

And I end with the following error message.

```
>Error in lhs - rhs : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I guess it's just a stupid basic mistake by another beginner, but I'd be extremely glad if anyone could help me out.

Next question would be, whether I can implement the fitted curve into my graph

```
>plot(x,y,main="VI.20.29")
```

Thanks to everyone taking time to read and hopefully answer my question!

Detailed information:
I have a table with the x values (Light.intensity) and y values (e.g. VI.20.29)

```
> photo.data<-read.csv("C:/X/Y/Z.csv", header=T)
    > names(photo.data)
     [1] "Light.intensity" "SR.8.6"          "SR.8.7"         
     [4] "SR.8.18"         "SR.8.20"         "VI.20.1"        
     [7] "VI.20.5"         "VI.20.20"        "VI.20.29"       
    [10] "DP.19.1"         "DP.19.15"        "DP.19.33"       
    [13] "DP.19.99"       
    > x<-photo.data$Light.intensity
    > x
    [1]    0   50  100  200  400  700 1000 1500 2000
    > y<-photo.data$VI.20.29
    > y
    [1] -2.76 -2.26 -1.72 -1.09  0.18  0.66  1.47  1.48  1.63
    > plot(x,y,main="VI.20.29")
    > Data<-data.frame(x,y)
    > Data
         x     y
    1    0 -2.76
    2   50 -2.26
    3  100 -1.72
    4  200 -1.09
    5  400  0.18
    6  700  0.66
    7 1000  1.47
    8 1500  1.48
    9 2000  1.63
    > g<-function(x,y,A,b,R) {
    +   y~A(1-exp(-bx))+R
    +   }
    > nls((y~g(x,y,A,b,R)),data=Data, start=list(A=-2,b=0,R=-5))
    Error in lhs - rhs : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: You need to include `*` explicitly: `y~A*(1-exp(-b*x))+R`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, but it does not work either... any more ideas? It drives me nuts to read all the online examples and being unable to use them properly...

    > g<-function(x,y,A,b,R) {
    +   y~A*(1-exp(-b*x))+R
    +   }
    > nls((y~g(x,y,A,b,R)),data=Data, start=list(A=-2,b=0,R=-5))
    Error in lhs - rhs : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Read the error message! A binary operator includes things like `-`, `*`, `~`, etc. Non-numeric means something isn't a number. Can you share the results of running `str(Data)` in your console, as well as `typeof(with(Data, g(x,y,A,b,R)))`?

Comment: Hi,
I got that any of my data or parameters or variables isn't recognised as a number, but I don't know what to change - my data is only numbers...
> str(Data)
'data.frame': 9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: int  0 50 100 200 400 700 1000 1500 2000
 $ y: num  -2.76 -2.26 -1.72 -1.09 0.18 0.66 1.47 1.48 1.63
> typeof(with(Data, g(x,y,A,b,R)))
[1] "language"
Thanks a lot for helping me understanding what I am doing!

Comment: It worked! I am so glad I achieved a big step towards understanding of R and how to use it for modelling my data - thanks to you guys, Roland and Senor O!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling a function within a function. You're saying `y~g(...)`, when **the function `g(...)` itself calls `y~(other variables)`**. It's kind of 'double counting' in a way.

Just do:

```
nls(y~A*(1-exp(-b*x))+R, data=Data, start=list(A=-2,b=0,R=-5))
```

Comment: I feel like I am getting closer:-)
    > nls(y~A*(1-exp(-b*x))+R, data=Data, start=list(A=0,b=0,R=0))
    Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
      singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
So I guess now I have to play with the parameter to make it work...

Comment: That's right, the problem right now is that `nls` is not able to find a good solution given your starting parameters. You will want to plot the data and try to improve your starting estimate. Also, you can take a guess at just 'b' and then run `lm(y~I(exp(-b*x)), Data)` to give you ideas for `A` and `R`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you did an awesome job! Now I was even able to plot that, and I'll further work on extracting the results and compute some more parameters, but I am confident I can do that - thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Your initial guess for parameters were way off. I saved your data in 'data.csv'
for this example that converges and then does the plot... To get this, I 
adjusted parameters to get close and then did the nls fit...

```
df <- read.csv('data.csv')
x <- df$x
y <- df$y
plot(x,y)

fit <- nls(y~A*(1-exp(-b*x))+R, data=df, start=list(A=3,b=0.005,R=-2))
s <- summary(fit)

A <- s[["parameters"]][1]
b <- s[["parameters"]][2]
R <- s[["parameters"]][3]

f <- function(z){
  v <- A*(1-exp(-b*z))+R
  v
}

x.t <- 0:max(x)
y.c <- sapply(x.t, f)
lines(x.t, y.c, col='red')
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Computers do what you tell them:

```
y~A(1-exp(-bx))+R
```

Here R interprets `A(...)` as a function and `bx` as a variable.

You want `y~A*(1-exp(-b*x))+R`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It still brings up the same error message anyway. Anything else I can do about that?